# Si mejoro la edición de otro usuario, ¿el otro usuario gana reputación?

Tags: soporte, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas, reputación

Me he encontrado una pregunta que tenía una edición pendiente de aprobación, y le he dado a mejorar edición para añadir un par de detalles. Mi edición no ha necesitado aprobación y se ha producido inmediatamente.

Lo que me queda es la duda si al usuario que tenía la edición pendiente ha recibido su recompensa, o realmente le he quitado indirectamente esa recompensa al editarla yo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, porque le has dado a *Mejorar edición*, que quiere decir que se acepta su edición y tú trabajas a partir de ella.

No se le daría si seleccionaras *Rechazar y editar*, en cuyo caso la edición se descarta y tú empiezas a trabajar en base a la edición existente (sin hacer caso de la sugerencia de edición).

En el caso particular que comentas, para confirmarlo a través de la [línea de tiempo de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/367499/timeline) puedes llegar a la sugerencia de edición en https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/218959

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te las sabes todas. ¡Gracias! :)

Comment: uff... que mala onda el texto de rechazo... lo modifiqué un poco [acá](https://es.traducir.win/strings/5229) (es mala onda la versión en inglés también, la traducción es literal)

Comment: @g3rv4 estoy de acuerdo, el redactado original es ciertamente más confrontativo de lo que debería. Bien por dejar ese _completamente superfluos_ en solamente _superfluos_, no hacía falta encarnizarse tanto :D